# Why does Kotlin lang allow only single main function in project?

Tags: kotlin

Doesn't this take away the feature of having multiple main entry points in java which can be called as and when required.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**UPDATE**: recent versions of Kotlin allow multiple `main` functions even in the same package (if they are in different files).

You can have multiple main functions in your project but only one main function per **package**

The reason why you can't make multiple main functions in package is that all functions in package are stored in Package class so you can't have multiple functions in a class with same signatures.

So if you want multiple main functions you **have to define them in different packages**

Comment: You can now have a main per Kotlin file.  Kotlin no longer generates a package level container class for all of the top-level functions, and instead creates a class per file.  If the filename is `App` and is in package `foo.bar` with your `main()` function, then the class name will be `foo.bar.AppKT` containing that `main()`

Comment: can you update your answer to be current, see comment above)

Comment: If you do, then all but one main function has to be private, otherwise there will be a name clash. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 24):

In addition to Sergey Mashkov's comment: you can put a `main` inside an object and mark it [`@JvmStatic`](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#static-methods-and-fields):

```
object Main {
    @JvmStatic 
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        println("Hello, world!")
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but beware, if you do this, you will not be able to use most of the features in `kotlin.reflect`, because not all of the classes will be loaded.